# Where is detailed documentation for bash build-in command?

Tags: bash

I want to know the meaning of `compgen` options.
With `help compgen` I can get help page.
But it shows only the option lists. There is no explanation for it.

> compgen: compgen [-abcdefgjksuv] [-o option]  [-A action] [-G globpat]
>   [-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix]
>   [-S suffix] [word]
>       Display possible completions depending on the options.
>
> ```
> Intended to be used from within a shell function generating possible
> completions.  If the optional WORD argument is supplied, matches against
> WORD are generated.
>
> Exit Status:
> Returns success unless an invalid option is supplied or an error occurs.
> ```

Especially I want know how `-abcdefgjksuv` arguments works.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near the bottom of the bash man page is the section SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS where it says

```
compgen [option] [word]
          Generate  possible  completion  matches  for  word according to the
          options, which may be any option accepted by the  complete  builtin
          with the exception of -p and -r, and write the matches to the stan-
          dard output.  When using the -F or -C options,  the  various  shell
          variables  set  by  the  programmable  completion facilities, while
          available, will not have useful values.

          The matches will be generated in  the  same  way  as  if  the  pro-
          grammable  completion  code had generated them directly from a com-
          pletion specification with the same flags.  If word  is  specified,
          only those completions matching word will be displayed.

          The  return  value is true unless an invalid option is supplied, or
          no matches were generated.
```

Just below it is the `complete` builtin command which explains the switches.